# Scope of variables in if statements

Tags: c++, constructor, scope

I have a class that has no default constructor or assignment operator so it is declared and initialized within an if/else statement depending on the result of another function. But then it says that it is out of scope later even though both routes of the conditional will create an instance.

Consider the following example (done with `int` just to illustrate the point):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  if(1) {
    int i = 5;
  } else {
    int i = 0;
  }

  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Do variables declared in a conditional go out of scope at the end of the conditional? What is the correct way to handle the situation where there is no default constructor but the arguments for the constructor depend on certain conditionals?

**Edit**

In light of the answers given, the situation is more complex so maybe the approach would have to change. There is an abstract base class A and two classes B and C that derive from A. How would something like this:

```
if(condition) {
   B obj(args);
} else {
   C obj(args);
}
```

change the approach? Since A is abstract, I couldn't just declare `A* obj` and create the appropriate type with `new`.

Comment: Is your inheritance virtual or static?

Comment: Virtual, I think. `class A` has a virtual function, if that's what you mean (C++ isn't my strong suit, I work mostly in Fortran)

Comment: You actually can declare a pointer to an abstract class - I edited my answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"Do variables declared in a conditional go out of scope at the end of the conditional?"

**Yes** - the scope of a local variable only falls within enclosing brackets:

```
{
   int x; //scope begins

   //...
}//scope ends
//x is not available here
```

In your case, say you have `class A`.

If you're not dealing with pointers:

```
A a( condition ? 1 : 2 );
```

or if you're using a different constructor prototype:

```
A a = condition ? A(1) : A(2,3);
```

If you're creating the instance on the heap:

```
A* instance = NULL;
if ( condition )
{
   instance = new A(1);
}
else
{
   instance = new A(2);
}
```

or you could use the ternary operator:

```
//if condition is true, call A(1), otherwise A(2)
A* instance = new A( condition ? 1 : 2 );
```

EDIT:

Yes you could:

```
A* x = NULL; //pointer to abstract class - it works
if ( condition )
   x = new B();
else
   x = new C();
```

EDIT:

It seems what you're looking for is the factory pattern (look it up):

```
 class A; //abstract
 class B : public A;
 class C : public A;

 class AFactory
 {
 public:
    A* create(int x)
    {
       if ( x == 0 )
          return new B;
       if ( x == 1 )
          return new C;
       return NULL;
    }
 };
```

Comment: Is the memory reallocated in this case ?? After the variable scope ends after the enclosing { } brackets.

Answer (score 5):

> Do variables declared in a conditional go out of scope at the end of
>   the conditional?

Yes.

> What is the correct way to handle the situation where there is no
>   default constructor but the arguments for the constructor depend on
>   certain conditionals?

Write a function that returns a value, from which you copy.

```
T foo()
{
    if(condition)
        return T(x);
    return T(y);
}

void bar()
{
    T i(foo());
}
```

**Edit:**

> Since A is abstract, I couldn't just declare A* obj and create the
>   appropriate type with new.

What do you mean?  That's exactly how dynamic typing works.  Except I wouldn't use a raw pointer, I would use a unique_ptr.

```
std::unique_ptr<A> obj;
if(condition) {
   obj = std::unique_ptr<A>(new B(args));
} else {
   obj = std::unique_ptr<A>(new C(args));
}
```

Comment: This answer contradicts the first answer? (about whether variables declared  in a conditional will go out of scope at the conditional's end)

Comment: @Gnuey: No it doesn't. I'm not sure exactly which question Luchian is answering "No" to. Perhaps he just got the verbiage confused between the time he read the question and the time he wrote the answer. But the full statement, as well as the commented code snippet that follows it, clearly agree with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative will be pointers:

```
MyObject *obj;
if(cond1)
{
    obj = new MyObject(1, 2, 3);
}
else
{
    obj = new MyObject(4, 5);
}
```

Remember to delete it when you are done with it, or use a smart pointer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will be out of scope if declared in a conditional, loop etc.  Will the type of the variable change depending on the conditional?

Comment: So there are both cases. Sometimes it is the same type regardless of the conditional, sometimes it is a different type depending on the conditional. How would the approaches change for the two situations?

Comment: I have. I see how it addresses the first case (same type). How does it address the possibility of different types being declared based on the conditional?