# Externing from a condition

Tags: c++, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scope of variables in if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543167/scope-of-variables-in-if-statements)

Say i have the following code;

```
int y = 5;
if (.... ) {
 int x = 10;
 x = y; 
}
```

Is there a way i can use the variable x outside of the if scope?

Comment: You could just declare `x` before the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

No. The scope of `x` is within the `if`. Declare `x` outside of the `if` if you want to use it elsewhere. If you try to reference `x` in the line following that `if` you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from putting `x` outside the `if` block, no. A variable can only be used within its scope.

This is what the C++ standard has to say about it in `basic.scope.declarative`:

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part
>   of the program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualiﬁed name
>   to refer to the same entity. In general, each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous
>   portion of program text called its scope.

As a consequence, using it elsewhere is invalid.