# C++ function initialization and memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

Are all variables within a C++ function pre-initialized when the function is called, regardless of where they are declared? I ask this as I would like to know if exiting a function before the entire function has been executed would lead to memory leaks of variables declared after a return statement. For instance:

```
string oddOrEven(int a)
{
 if ((a % 2) != 0)
 {
    string odd{ "the number is odd" };
    return odd;
 }
 else
 {
    string even{ "the number is even" };
    return even;
 }
}
```

*This piece of code is just for demonstration purposes.*

If it were an odd number that was handed to the function, would the string even{} never be created? Because if it were to be created, wouldnt that mean that the string will become a memory leak when the function was exited in the first part of the if-else block?

Comment: What are you talking about here, the strings are local variables created on the stack, you have an `if` branch here so they are different code paths, there is no leak here

Comment: If you're asking whether scope dictates both birth, and death of an automatic variable, the answer is yes.

Comment: where is memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `even` is local to the else block and wouldn't be created if `a` had been odd.

NOTE: Local variables, even those declared directly inside a function, are NOT auto-initialized; only global variables declared outside all functions are auto-initialized..

REFERENCES:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

From the URL below: "A local variable declared inside a conditional (block) will go out of scope at the end of the conditional."

[Scope of variables in if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543167/scope-of-variables-in-if-statements)

Answer (score 0):

Once your program leaves the function `oddOrEven(int a)`, all of the local variables of that function are destroyed and returns your `string`

Answer (score 0):

If it were an odd number that was handed to the function,the string even{} never be created.

Answer (score 0):

The point that the other answers are trying to address is that ALL local variables including either `odd` or `even` are destroyed on exit from the scope in which they are created.

`odd` (or `even`) is NOT what is returned from the function.  What is returned is a temporary copy of `odd` or `even` and the caller knows to delete this copy.

Note: this is ignoring Return Value Optimization (RVO) because that would only make the situation more confusing.