# Declare two different types of variables with general Scope using an if...else statement?

Tags: c++, variables, scope, scoping

Depending on a condition, I have to declare a new variable that is either a NumericVector or NumericMatrix that later will be used for further processing. I have attempted the following approach:

```
if(condition) 
{
     NumericVector var(n_samples);
}else{
     NumericMatrix var(n_samples, n_column);
}

if(condition) 
{
     #Further code to process var as NumericVector
}else{
     #Further code to process var as NumericMatrix
}

return(var)
```

But we all know that [C++ variables go out scope at the end of the conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543167/scope-of-variables-in-if-statements) and that is exactly what I am getting.

```
Line xxx: var was not declared in this scope
```

I have tried with a pointer without success.

```
Object *var = NULL;
if(condition) 
{
    var = new NumericVector Object(n_samples);
}else{
    var = new NumericMatrix Object(n_samples, n_column);
}
```

Is there a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Do your types derive from `Object`?

Comment: Please look up how `new` expressions work. This seems like a basic syntax error.

Comment: What was the problem with your `Object*` approach?

Comment: Are both the `NumericVector` and the `NumericMatrix` used in **exactly the same way** in the subsequent code?

Comment: I know Object must be something like NumericVector, or int, but that wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Then what is your problem? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Galik Essentially there are another of if...else statement. If the condition is true, code is made to deal with a vector. If it is false, it is made to deal with a Matrix. At last, I should be able to return(var) wether it is a NumericVector or NumericMatrix.

Comment: @j91 So `condition` is a runtime requirement actually? Consider an Abstract Factory then.

Comment: This sounds like you need to design your program a little differently. Rather than have lots of `if/else` everywhere you could have **just one** `if/else` and do the whole processing for the selected type. Use your first method.

Comment: @Galik I have included more pseudocode to make the question clearer. The problem is that some calculations are the same and I don't want to extend my code unnecessarily.

Comment: At the end of the day you can't write code to do two different jobs using two different types at the same time. Write two blocks of code instead.

Comment: @j91 I think some redundancy is inevitable but what you are trying to do is not the way to reduce it. There will likely be other ways to reduce redundancy but this is not a good one.

Comment: For example you could probably write some *generic functions* to deal with those times when you process a `NumericVector` and a `NumericMatrix` in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a template is for.

```
template<typename var_type>
void do_something_with_var(var_type &var)
{
    // The rest of the code that uses var.
}

// .....

if(condition) 
{
     NumericVector var(n_samples);
     do_something_with_var(var);
} else {
     NumericMatrix var(n_samples, n_column);
     do_something_with_var(var);
}
```

If `do_something_with_var()` needs to use some additional objects, variables, etc..., from the scope that calls it, just pass them as additional parameters to `do_something_with_var()`.

This will also introduce you to another C++ feature called "template code bloat". If both `NumericMatrix` and `NumericVar` derive from the same superclass, like your `Object`, it would be possible to avoid code bloat by making `do_something_with_var()` a regular function that takes an `Object &` parameter, and implement all subclass-specific functionality as virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

The second "with a pointer" will work, as long as both your types are derived from `Object`, and the "further code" only performs operations supported by `Object`.  If `Object` is polymorphic (e.g. it provides `virtual` functions that are specialised by the derived classes), then use of those virtual functions will work too.

If the "further code" tries to do any operations that are specific to either `NumericVector` or `NumericMatrix`  (i.e. not supported by, or inherited from, `Object`) then those operations will also not compile.

If `NumericVector` and `NumericMatrix` support a common set of operations (with or without a common base class), you can also use a templated function.

From a design perspective, I would try to eliminate the `NumericVector` type completely.    A `NumericMatrix` with one column would (presumably) be equivalent.   If you do that, you could do

```
 NumericMatrix var(n_samples, (condition ? 1 : n_column));
```

as long as you ensure that subsequent code does not directly pass `n_column` to `var`s member functions.

Comment: "From a design perspective, I would try to eliminate the NumericVector type completely. A NumericMatrix with one column would (presumably) be equivalent." I told that to my Professor, and the code was written to work with that in mind. He didn't like it and that is why I am asking here how to solve the problem without rewriting everything.

Comment: That's between you and your professor.   In general terms, a Vector is often a Matrix with one column (or row, depending on how you've specified it).   If you can't make that case, it means there is either more information about your problem than you've described here or you haven't convinced your professor - either way, the problem cannot be solved by people online.