# Mathematically identical variables - one breaks shader one doesn't

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I've written a fragment shader that works with one variable declaration but breaks with another that is mathematically identical.  I have edited the code snippet to highlight the two alternatives for `thetastrt_2`. `PI` is properly defined and `partsnum` is a float that equals 3.0 -

```
fragmentShader: [

    "uniform vec3 mixfinal;",
    //more uniforms

    "vec3 mixer () {",
    "   vec3 lightOG = vec3 ( 0.0 );",          
    "   float thetastrt_0 = PI / 2.0;",
    "   if ( partsnum >= 2.0 ) {",
    "       float thetastrt_1 =  thetastrt_0 + ( PI * 2.0 / partsnum );",
            //more code
    "   }",
    "   if ( partsnum >= 3.0 ) {",

    "       float thetastrt_2 =  thetastrt_0 + ( PI * 4.0 / partsnum );", //shader works

    "       float thetastrt_2 =  thetastrt_1 + ( PI * 2.0 / partsnum );", //shader breaks

            //more code
    "   }",
    "   return lightOG;",
    "}",    //end mixer ()

    "void main() {",
    "   vec3 outgoingLight = vec3( 0.0 );", 
    "   outgoingLight = mixer();",
        //more code
    "}"
```

With no debugger this was hard to find.  Is this a run/compile time issue?  Is the problem that `thetastrt_2` depends on `thetastrt_1` depends on `thetastrt_0`?

Comment: OpenGL ES compiler time errors generally include very good error messages, just a like a C compiler. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Shader_error_handling

Comment: @solidpixel Thank you and also to Rabbid76.  I'm in a Visual Studio - Cordova - WebGL environment, and the error messages were "invalid shader" with no detail.  And I've just learned that if statements have scope in C.  Thank you.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you for your comment.  I've programmed mostly in javascript and have now learned that the scoping rules for js - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript?rq=1 - are different than for other languages - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543167/scope-of-variables-in-if-statements   If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it with many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
if ( partsnum >= 2.0 ) {
    float thetastrt_1 =  thetastrt_0 + ( PI * 2.0 / partsnum );
    ....
}
```

`float thetastrt_1` is declared in the scope of the `if`-statement, so it is not accessible anymore outside the `if`-statement block.

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification; 4.2.2 Types of Scope; page 44 and 45](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf)

> The scope of a variable is determined by where it is declared. .....
>
> Representing the if construct as:
>
> **if** *if-expression* **then** *if-statement* **else** *else-statement*,
>
> **a variable declared in the if-statement is scoped to the end of the if-statement**.  A variable declared in the else-statement is scoped to the end of the else-statement.