# I dont understand why this wont work

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. It seems like it just skips the if statements. I get the error that `y` isn't initialized, when I add `int y = 0;` before the if statements it just always takes the zero.

Maybe I'm just overlooking something simple? Here is my code:

```css
// ConsoleApplication9.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum MonsterType
{
 MONSTER_ORC,
 MONSTER_GOBLIN,
 MONSTER_TROLL,
 MONSTER_OGRE,
 MONSTER_SKELETON,
};

int getUser()
{
 std::cout << "Pick a door, 1 - 5 " << std::endl;
 int x;
 std::cin >> x;

 return x;
}

std::string getMonName(int y)
{
 if (y == MONSTER_ORC)
  return std::string("Orc");
 if (y == MONSTER_GOBLIN)
  return std::string("Goblin");
 if (y == MONSTER_TROLL)
  return std::string("Troll");
 if (y == MONSTER_OGRE)
  return std::string("Ogre");
 if (y == MONSTER_SKELETON)
  return std::string("Skeleton");
 else
  return std::string("???");
}

void getMon(int x)
{   
 if (x == 1)
  int y = 0;
 if (x == 2)
  int y = 1;
 if (x == 3)
  int y = 2;
 if (x == 4)
  int y = 3;
 if (x == 5)
  int y = 4;

 std::cout << "You see a " << getMonName(y) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
 int x = getUser();
 getMon(x);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scope of variables in if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543167/scope-of-variables-in-if-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int y = 0; // Declare and initialize y here!

if (x == 1)
    y = 0; // No int before y
```

and so on for your other cases, so that `y` is seen outside of the `if` scope. I would suggest using the following syntax:

```
int y = 0;

if (x == 1)
{
    y = 0;
}
```

So as to more clearly identify the scope.

Comment: I tried that but I just get uninitialized local variable 'y' used (refering to std::cout << "You see a " << getMonName(y) << "\n";)

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: @AnthonyMaringelli Please mark the answer as solved if it works so that other users do not write their own for nothing.

Comment: absolutly just gotta wait 3 mins for it to let me ;)

Comment: Do you really need all the if ()s in getMon()? I mean `y=x-1` unless x <1 or x> 5.

Comment: I dont think so I just wanted to get it to work lol, plus i altered a test from learncpp.com

Answer (score 1):

In getMon, y is declared and destroyed at every if statement which might be creating the issue. Instead you could rewrite the function in a similar fashion.

```
void getMon(int x) {
  int y = (x >=1 && x<=5) ? x-1:0;
  std::cout << "You see a " << getMonName(y) << "\n";
}
```