# How do I set a string value inside an if statement? (C++)

Tags: c++

This may seem like a stupid question but how do I keep a variable value when it is assigned inside a if statement?
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string usability;
    string bent;
    string usable;
    string input = "bent";

    if(input.find(bent) != string::npos)
    {
        string usability = "bent";
    }
    if(input.find(usable) != string ::npos)
    {
        string usability = "usable";
    }    

    cout << usability;
    return 0;
}
```

The string usability at the end is still empty. (I assume because the variable is only set in its own if statement?) How do I get it to print "bent" or "usable"?

Thanks

Comment: Just omit the `string` inside the if blocks, otherwise you declare local variables which shadow the originally declared variable inside te block.

Comment: exactly, so just declare it outside the if statement and then set it inside

Comment: Don't declare a new variable.    In the `if`  do `usability = "bent"` to affect the previously declared `usability` (in `main()`).   `string usability = "bent"` defines a new variable with the same name which hides the previously defined one, and then ceases to exist at the end of the `{}` block.

Comment: take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543167/scope-of-variables-in-if-statements,  Ken?

Comment: You should search for and enable several compiler warnings.  In this case,  -Wshadow generates:  "warning: declaration of ‘usability’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]"    I normally use about 30 options.  The warning text has improved, and if g++ confuses me, I try clang++, which can provide a more useful warning.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't recreate the variable, use the one already existing.

```
if(input.find(bent) != string::npos)
{
   usability = "bent";
}
if(input.find(usable) != string ::npos)
{
   usability = "usable";
}
```