# why can't I assign the value of one variable to another?

Tags: c++

I have two variables and I want to work with the bigger and the smaller one  differently.

My approach:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;

if (a >= b){
    int c = a;
    int d = b;
}
else{
    int c = b;
    int d = a;
}
```

I obtained an error of unused variable and when I try to use `c` and `d` later, it says

> `c` could not be resolved

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope This provides some good guidance on how where you declare stuff in general affects where/how you can then use it at later points in your program

Comment: Duplicate of [Scope of variables in if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543167/scope-of-variables-in-if-statements)

Answer (score 30):

In both cases `c` and `d` are *scoped* to the braces in the `if` `else` block, so you can't access them outside that.

You need something of the form

```
int c, d;
if (a >= b){
    c = a;
    d = b;
} else {
    c = b;
    d = a;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

As other have pointed out the issue here is where you declare the variables.  You cannot use them outside of the scope they are declared in so you get an error.

If you can use C++17 then you can fix the code by using [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) and a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) like

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    auto [min, max] = std::minmax(b, a);
    std::cout << min << " " << max;
}
```

which is really nice because now you don't have variables that are uninitialized for any amount of time.

Comment: It's really really nice.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yep.  I love it because it very clearly expresses what you are trying to do.  From a maintainability standpoint, that's gold.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you are declaring the variables in an `if` statement.

Logically you may be of the belief that the `else` in a way guarantees that the variables will be assigned if the declaration is in both the `if` and also in the `else` block.

The correct way to do it is to just declare the variables before the `if` block, otherwise the variables use will be restricted to the scope from which it was declared.

Also, you can do this without the need for an `if` and `else` by using ternary operations:

```
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;

        int c = a >= b ? a : b;
        int d = b < a ? b : a;
```

With this type of syntax, you can save yourself the hassle of writing `if` and `else` blocks for simple variable assignments. The variable *after* the `?` is the result if the condition is true, and the variable after the `:` is the result if the condition is false.

Comment: The problem is not *setting* variables in an `if` statement, the problem is *declaring* them in there.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but this is certainly because of the lack of explanations

Comment: It has nothing to do where the variables are "set".  It is where where they are declared.  This answer really need some fleshing out.

Comment: @Angew understood. Of course this is what I meant. I will edit.

Comment: `the declaration […] may or may not actually happen` - this is what troubles me. It's also wrong as either branch will be executed so declaration will happen. This is, of course, irrelevant as the scope ends but for someone who doesn't understand the concept of scoping this will enhance their confusion.

Comment: The problem with the ternary approach is that you essentially repeat the condition check.

Comment: @Bathsheba true, but I would argue that if the condition check is a constant time operation, such as checking whether an `int` is greater than or less than some other `int`, then the repeating of the condition check is justifiable if it makes the code more readable. Just my perspective.

Comment: @ElroyJetson: It's *maintainability*, not performance that concerns me here.

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks for adding your perspective. I myself believe that by making something more **readable** it actually increases **maintainability** I just think `if` `else` blocks for assigning variables can sometimes be better served as a ternary statement. Just my opinion

Comment: @StackDanny I agree

Comment: @ElroyJetson the problem is what if you spot the bug that you got the variables the wrong way round, so you correct it. But now you have to fix it in 2 places. If it becomes more complex in the future you have to maintain the code twice.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 aha! Thanks for your explanation, I had never really considered that. I guess my underlying assumption is that your ternary statements should be simple by nature, i.e. if it starts becoming complex then the ternary statement is the wrong tool for the job. But your point is something I had not considered before. I will keep this in mind!

Answer (score 4):

That's a scope problem, you are creating the variables inside a scope and they can't be accessed outside

```
if (a >= b){
    int c = a;  // c and d belongs to that if scope
    int d = b;
}
else{
    int c = b;  // c and d belongs to that else scope
    int d = a;
}
```

Change your code to this :

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
int c;
int d;

if (a >= b){
    c = a;
    d = b;
}
else{
    c = b;
    d = a;
}
// You can now call c and d there
```

---

A way to shorten that code would be to store the boolean value of `a >= b` and use it in a ternary expression to set `c` and `d`

In example :

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
bool IsAGreaterOrEqualToB = (a >= b);
int c = ((IsAGreaterOrEqualToB) ? (a) : (b));
int d = ((IsAGreaterOrEqualToB) ? (b) : (a));
```

Comment: You've got quite a few brackets there. How come? Also I'd add in some `const` but otherwise yes this is good. Prefer init over assignment!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this is an old habit I have. Like when I return something, I am used to write : `return (MyVar);`

Comment: Okay, but why is that? It just adds noise! `? (a) : (b)` is harder to read than `? a : b` :(

Comment: @Cid: That is occasionally harmful in C++ by the way.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's just an habit, it helped me to separate the differents parts (especially when i wrote some nested ternary) Feel free to edit my answer if you think this may be more readable, answers are made for others

Comment: @Bathsheba would you please point me some examples ? I'm curious

Comment: @Cid: It wreaks havoc with `decltype(auto)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto

Comment: Doesn't it also prevent RVO? Perhaps even the xvalueness of the result, preventing a move (C++17)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25615981/560648 at least. Really, try to avoid superfluous parens.

Comment: There's no need for the extra variable.  `(a >= b) ? a : b` is at least as clear as `(IsAGreaterOrEqualToB) ? (a) : (b)`, and any reasonable optimizing compiler will recognize the potential for common subexpression elimination, so it's not less efficient either.